# Have a graphviz digraph transfered to svg and included into a dart webapp. But the anchor is is not available at onclick method

Tags: html, svg, dart

With the following cod I read an svg string from a server and put it into the dom.

```
HttpRequest.getString('http://das-struxt.net/service/getText/filename/top-rubrik.svg').then((String results ) {
   print(results);
   var validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
      ..allowHtml5()
      ..allowSvg();

   DivElement dcontainer = new DivElement();
   dcontainer.id="content";
   dcontainer.setInnerHtml(results, validator: validator);
   document.querySelector('#primary').append(dcontainer);
});
```

That really works fine. The svg stream looks like this:

```
<svg width="980pt" height="346pt"
   viewBox="0.00 0.00 980.00 346.00"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 342)">
 <title>TRTopRubriken</title>
 <polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-342 976,-342 976,4 -4,4"/>
  <!-- Angebote -->
  <g id="node1" class="node"><title>Angebote</title>
  <g id="a_node1">
   <a xlink:href="http://das-struxt.net/getrubrik/rubrik/Angebote"   

    xlink:title="Angebote" 
     xlink:id="info_angebote">
     <polygon fill="green" .../>
     <text text-anchor=....fill="white">Angebote</text>
    </a>
```

but I try to get the id info_angebote while clicking the anchor I get an element without id

```
document.body.onClick.listen((e) {   
  var clickedElem = e.target;
  var attr = clickedElem.attributes;
  attr.forEach((k,v) => print(k+'='+v));
  print('You clicked the ${clickedElem.id}- Element');
  populateAllClicks(e,clickedElem.id);
});
```

then I get the following result printed.

```
text-anchor=middle
x=160
y=-318.7
font-family=sans serif
font-size=6.00
fill=white
**You clicked the - Element**
```

**First: why will this code not work  ?**

**Second: Is there a better solution for using somethink like a button in svg which I can use later on in the onclick-Method for further REST-Queries**
Thank you Christian (Flens)

Comment: I guess this is a namespace problem!

Comment: I tried it also without any namespace,using only the id-tag, but that didn't work too.

Comment: The .svg file doesn't load for me anymore?

Answer (score 1):

So ... here is the solution:

First of all document.onClick always returns the textNode and not the anchor. That's why I had to make a little modification to your code. This is the solution:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  HttpRequest.getString('sample.svg').then((String results ) {
     var validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
        ..allowHtml5()
        ..allowSvg();

     DivElement dcontainer = new DivElement();
     dcontainer.id="content";
     dcontainer.setInnerHtml(results, validator: validator);
     document.querySelector('#svg').append(dcontainer);

     document.querySelector('#content a').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       Element a = e.currentTarget;
       print("href:" + a.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href'));
       print("title:" + a.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'title'));
       print("id:" + a.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'id'));
       var attr = a.getNamespacedAttributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
       attr.forEach((k,v) {
         print(k + " = " + v);
       });
     });
  });
}
```

There also is

```
a.getNamespacedAttributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
```

But that doesn't give me the values of the attributes.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** the xlink namespace doesn't define an id attribute so that's why you will get an empty string for "id".

```
<svg width="980pt" height="346pt"
   viewBox="0.00 0.00 980.00 346.00"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 342)">
 <title>TRTopRubriken</title>
 <polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-342 976,-342 976,4 -4,4"/>
  <!-- Angebote -->
  <g id="node1" class="node"><title>Angebote</title>
  <g id="a_node1">
   <a xlink:href="http://das-struxt.net/getrubrik/rubrik/Angebote"   

    xlink:title="Angebote" 
     xlink:id="info_angebote">
     <polygon fill="green" .../>
     <text text-anchor=....fill="white">Angebote</text>
    </a>
  </g>
  </polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Regards
Robert

Comment: Thank you Robert, it seems me to be very near to a good solution, but if I use your cod I only get empty prints.